# How To Deploy Angular 7 with Net Core API Separately on Azure

Tags: angular, azure, asp.net-core, .net-core, angular7

Right now I have a .Net Core Application with Angular 7 as the Client

I have both the API and Client deployed on Azure however I am stuck on how to get the client working on azure where it reaches the .Net Core endpoints. On my login post request I am getting a 404 however it works on my local build... I'm not sure exaclty what I'm doing wrong?

```
    Request Method: POST
Status Code: 404 Not Found
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question title and the actual question is different.

You need to check from the application level if there is a [network/CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) issue
while making the Login request.

You need to check if the API end point is live and working as expected with
some tools like [POSTMAN](https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending-api-requests/requests/).

If you are not able to figure out the issue, I recommend you to add Application
Insights and check for custom errors with the [login Request(Parameters)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-exceptions)